# what is the need to use Dynamic programming approach for egg dropping puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, puzzle

I was solving DP related problems, i encountered generalized [egg dropping puzzle](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-11-egg-dropping-puzzle/).
I could solve this using divide and conquer where subProblems are not repeated. so i believe DP is not needed to solve the egg dropping puzzle.
Can anyone tell if the following algorithm works where there is no need for DP

```
n- eggs
k-floors
initial call : eggDroppingPuzzle(n,k)
eggDroppingPuzzle(eggs, floor)
{
 if floor==1 return 1;
 else if eggs=1 return K;
 return 1+eggDroppingPuzzle(n-1,k/2-1);// problem is reduced by (size/2)-1
}
```

Since there is no overlapping subproblems in each recursive call, i feel there is no need for Dynamic programming.

Can someone explain if my algorithm which doesn't need DP is correct. If its not correct, explain me the correct algorithm which uses DP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code asserts (excluding edge cases)

```
eggDroppingPuzzle(eggs, floor) = 1+eggDroppingPuzzle(n-1,k/2-1)
```

This means:

- you're assuming the egg breaks for every drop (since n-1 remaining eggs), and
- your strategy is to always keep dropping from the middle of the remaining floors (since k/2 -1 remaining floors)

Both these assumptions are in general false, since the aim is to minimize the number of drops. For example, with your strategy,

eggDroppingPuzzle(2, 100) = 1 + eggDroppingPuzzle(1, 49)

And since eggDroppingPuzzle(1, 49) = 49, this means, for you eggDroppingPuzzle(2, 100) = 50, which is far greater than the correct answer 14. This is because your strategy is not optimal because of these faulty assumptions.

The recursive strategy makes no such assumptions. It simply states the obvious:
eggDrop(n, k) = 1 + min{max(eggDrop(n - 1, x - 1), eggDrop(n, k - x)): 
             where x in {1, 2, ..., k}}

The dynamic programming, clearly, is just the bottom up approach of the recursive logic where you trade time (repeated calculation) for space (stored array).
And yes, the DP approach is sort of an optimized way to brute force. There is no clever strategy involved. Just exploring all states till the solution state.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a closed form for optimal egg dropping, but that's not it. With two eggs, you're going to drop the first one from halfway up and then be very sorry if it cracks, because you'll have to make about `k/2` drops with the second. A better (but not optimal!) two-egg strategy is to go up `√k` floors at a time with the first egg for a maximum of `k/√k = √k` drops, making at most `√k` drops with the second. In general, the dynamic program optimally trades off the value of splitting the search space evenly with the cost of breaking eggs.

Comment: I don't understand when you u say "better but not optimal". 
Anyways. can u check the algorithm in the link provided and my algorithm in the question and explain me  if i have made any mistake.

Comment: @stallion The two-egg algorithm implied by your code makes Theta(k) drops in the worst case. The one I sketched makes Theta(√k), but the big-O constant has room for improvement.